# Google Maps won't appear on Android Device

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So I was trying to implements make a simple Google Map application for Android and the maps didn't show. All I see is grey screen. And I get these error message from LogCat

```
05-27 22:04:24.569: E/dalvikvm(12361): No free temp registers
05-27 22:04:24.569: E/dalvikvm(12361): Jit: aborting trace compilation, reverting to interpreter
05-27 22:04:32.869: E/AndroidRuntime(7051): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
05-27 22:04:33.699: E/AndroidRuntime(7064): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
05-27 22:04:34.369: E/AxT9IME(12326): setEditorType() - restarting : false
05-27 22:04:34.369: E/AxT9IME(12326):  mRestartRequested : false
05-27 22:04:34.369: E/AxT9IME(12326):  mIsScreenLocked : false
05-27 22:04:34.369: E/Vivek(12326): mInputLanguage = 429
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: you have entered the key correctly right?

Comment: Just make sure you have done everything from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: do you mean the API key? yeah, I have entered the right key

Answer (score 2):

This problem is usually derived from a problem in referencing `google-play-service` library.
Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps in your application, especially the first 3 steps:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

another cause of this could be that you haven't configured the Google API Console properly, so I suggest you to take a look at this guide as well:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

another reason that may cause this is if you have some kind of problem in your permissions in the manifest file. You can look at the first guide for the needed permissions as well.

Comment: yeah that's what I got only a blank map and zoom controls.do you have the link for that blog post of yours?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="<key here>" />`

About the value, I think you can have quick search on google and you can know it.
Normally, if you are developing, it'll use the `debug.keystore`

`%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`

Please also check if in your AndroidManifest have this:

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="<your_package>.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />`

And this:

`<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />`

Comment: @nnhthuan: If the key you are showing for demonstration here is a valid key, it might be a good idea to not show the key in public ;)

Comment: @user2401810: Please check again the new update in AndroidManifest in my reply

Comment: @ShobhitPuri: Thanks, I changed it as you suggest.