# FragmentActivity showing blank map on device, what could be the reason behind that?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

My problem is that the google maps is not showing on my android device 2.3.0
    I am new in android and i am trying to use google map in my app, i have downloaded google play services, also have added adndroidsupportv4.jar, i have generated api key by using sha1, after completing all steps map not yet visible on device, what could be the problem behind that, can any one help me. Even i have dowloaded google play services emulator shows an error that google play services not installed, so what i have made mistake while developing google map application

```
My code is:
below is the MainActivity class


package com.example.androdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map =((SupportMapFragment)
                (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map) )).getMap();
       // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    }


}

activity_main.xml 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB62caTnqcZoZil2lBc_qinUfNKNDmijRI"/>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775906/google-maps-wont-appear-on-android-device/16776089#16776089

Comment: My Logcat shows Authorization error

Comment: Have you referred google play services library project in your android map project. Also check if you have enabled maps for android in the api console. Also i suggest you test it on a device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator. pls check the link. you must test it on a real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing to check is that the internet is available on your android device.

I was developing an app that used google maps and they'd been working.  I had no idea what was going on when suddenly they didn't appear.  It turned out to be the lack of an internet connection that caused the problem!

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue, and the resolution was to generate a signed apk in order to view the map. i couldn't just view it on run or debug. had to be the signed application.